# Is there any version of arithmetic based on quantum logic? If so are they complete?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, incompleteness

I know that there are versions of arithmetic that are complete and self-consistent but they all miss some aspects of numbers as we know : [Systems which contain arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Formal_systems:_completeness,_consistency,_and_effective_axiomatization:%7E:text=in%20set%20theory.-,Systems%20which%20contain%20arithmetic,-%5Bedit%5D)

If so, have there been any attempts towards a quantum logic-based arithmetic, where it encompasses all aspects of numbers and is complete and self-consistent?

Comment: Any consistent theory has a complete (and consistent) extension.  I don't know how you want to work "quantum logic" into the picture. Please clarify your purpose/motivation.

Comment: But isn't what you say against Godel's incompleteness theorem? that any theory can not be complete and self-consistent at the same time if it can reproduce arithmetic. @hardmath

Comment: What @hardmath says is correct. Gödel’s theorem says you cannot have a theory that is recursive, consistent, complete, and extends Peano arithmetic. So the extensions he discusses are necessarily not recursive.

Comment: Quantum logic has nothing to do with arithmetic.

Comment: @MarkSaving Could you please define recursive in this context?

Comment: Maybe useful: ML Dalla Chiara and R Giuntini, ["Quantum Logics"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25303784.pdf), in Handbook of Philosophical Logic, vol. 6, 2002. See conclusion about "a kind of *logical schizophrenia* regarding the quantum physicist... the issue maybe is: is the *arithmetic* used by the quantum physicist different from the "classical one"?

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA But let's be more open to physics, I do traditional theoretical physics that does not care for rigore, none the less I think we are on the same bout one way or another :)

Comment: A theory $W$ is recursive when is some algorithm $T$ such that, when $T$ is called on input $\phi$, $T$ will eventually halt if and only if $\phi \in W$. Equivalently, it means there is some formal way of writing proofs and some algorithm $Q$ which, given $x$ and $\phi$, will return whether $x$ is a proof of $\phi$, and where $W = \{\phi \mid $ there is some proof of $\phi\}$.